# Import error while importing nltk (Cannot import bracket_parse)

Tags: python, ubuntu, nltk

I have installed nltk and nltk-data. Program gives error on
`import nltk`.

Below is error stack trace:

```
import nltk
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
from nltk.stem import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/stem/snowball.py", line 24, in <module>
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/__init__.py", line 66, in <module>
from nltk.corpus.reader import *
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/__init__.py", line 109, in <module>
from nltk.corpus.reader import bracket_parse
ImportError: cannot import name bracket_parse
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you installed NLTK?

Comment: I have installed nltk using sudo pip install -U nltk. It worked initially i had installed sklearn from pip install -U scikit-learn along with scipy and npmpy i am unable to figure out what is wrong

Comment: It may conflict with file names in your project. Check project's file names

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace shows that the error occurs several levels deep into the first import. So we can rule out the usual culprit, a file named `nltk.py` in your working directory. I'm guessing something went wrong with your nltk installation-- perhaps it was interrupted and you didn't notice?

Check if the file `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/bracket_parse.py` exists. I think there's any way to get the exact error trace you report if the file is present. If it's absent, I recommend zapping and reinstalling the `nltk` from scratch. (`nltk_data` can stay, and is easier to update from inside the system anyway if something is wrong.)

Answer (score -1):

Installed NLTK on Ubuntu 14.04 via following steps:

1. Install Setuptools: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools
2. Install Pip: run sudo easy_install pip
3. Install Numpy (optional): run sudo pip install -U numpy
4. Install NLTK: run sudo pip install -U nltk
5. Test installation: run python then type import nltk

Hope it helps

Comment: I had already install it. I had checked the installation it's all fine. After installing sklearn from pip install -U scikit-learn along with scipy and npmpy. It is showing errors. Code was working fine before installing sklearn

Comment: Even after installation of scikit-learn, I am able to import _bracket_parse_, can you try uninstalling the respective packages through _pip uninstall_ and installing it back.